# How do you convert bunch of columns to numeric in R

Tags: r

this is my df:

```
    structure(list(Time = structure(c(3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1/20/15 10:26 AM", 
"1/20/15 11:26 AM", "1/20/15 6:26 AM", "1/20/15 7:26 AM", "1/20/15 8:26 AM", 
"1/20/15 9:26 AM"), class = "factor"), Server1 = structure(c(1L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 6L), .Label = c("1.08", "12.08", "15", "4", "7.92", 
"No data"), class = "factor"), Server2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1.67", "4.33", "7.75", "No data"
), class = "factor"), Server3 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 
6L), .Label = c("0.83", "2.33", "3.58", "3.92", "4", "No data"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Time", "Server1", "Server2", 
"Server3"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I need to be able to convert all cells to numeric. When I do

```
data$Server1<-as.numeric(data$Server1)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Server", value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 6
```

Also, I like to be able to convert the columns to numeric by not individually referencing by data$Server1, or data$Server2, I may have several hundred columns.

Is there a better way to convert all columns to numeric and replacing non numeric cells to NA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `lapply()` to apply a function across the columns of interest.  I presume you want to leave the `Time` column intact, so we can leave that one out with a `[-1]` index.

```
## change all 'No data' elements to NA
is.na(df) <- df == "No data"
## for columns 2:4, drop extra factor levels and convert to numeric
df[-1] <- lapply(droplevels(df)[-1], function(x) as.numeric(levels(x))[x])
```

which gives

```
df
              Time Server1 Server2 Server3
1  1/20/15 6:26 AM    1.08    1.67    0.83
2  1/20/15 7:26 AM    4.00    4.33    2.33
3  1/20/15 8:26 AM    7.92      NA    3.58
4  1/20/15 9:26 AM   12.08      NA    4.00
5 1/20/15 10:26 AM   15.00    7.75    3.92
6 1/20/15 11:26 AM      NA      NA      NA
```

But you can likely solve this problem when you read the data into R by using the `na.strings` argument in your read call, which would eliminate the need to fix the columns after reading.

```
read.table(file, na.strings = "No data")
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_each(funs(as.numeric(levels(.))[.]), -Time)
```

You get:

```
#              Time Server1 Server2 Server3
#1  1/20/15 6:26 AM    1.08    1.67    0.83
#2  1/20/15 7:26 AM    4.00    4.33    2.33
#3  1/20/15 8:26 AM    7.92      NA    3.58
#4  1/20/15 9:26 AM   12.08      NA    4.00
#5 1/20/15 10:26 AM   15.00    7.75    3.92
#6 1/20/15 11:26 AM      NA      NA      NA
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data <- replace(data, data == "No data", NA)

cbind(data[1], apply(data[-1], 2, function(x) as.double(as.character(x))))
              Time Server1 Server2 Server3
1  1/20/15 6:26 AM    1.08    1.67    0.83
2  1/20/15 7:26 AM    4.00    4.33    2.33
3  1/20/15 8:26 AM    7.92      NA    3.58
4  1/20/15 9:26 AM   12.08      NA    4.00
5 1/20/15 10:26 AM   15.00    7.75    3.92
6 1/20/15 11:26 AM      NA      NA      NA
```

Answer (score 1):

My option would be

```
df[, 2:ncol(df)] <- apply(df[, 2:ncol(df)], 2, as.numeric)
```

as this seems most to-the-point. There is no need to change 'No data' to 'NA' as this is automatically done and you will get a warning message to notify that this happened.